# Calculate the distance to the sea of several points in ArcMap 10.8

Tags: arcmap, polygon, point, distance

I am a ArcMap user. I have a layer of points representing weather stations located inside an island. In turn, I have another layer (polygon) that represents the boundary of the island. The points inside this polygon are inside the island and what is outside is the sea.

For a meteorological study, I want to calculate the distance of each weather station (point) to the sea (polygon). That is, how far each point is from the sea. I have thousands of weather stations, so I need an ArcGIS tool to make this calculation.

I have tried to use the buffer tool to classify the stations according to different distances, but the buffer is always created towards the outside of the polygon (towards the sea) and not towards the inside. I have also tried using the Euclidean distance without a positive result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Convert the polygon to polyline and *then* compute nearest distance in vector space

Comment: It worked! It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Vince's comments:

1. Convert your polygon data into a polyline dataset, you can do this with the [Feature to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm) tool.
2. Run the [Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) tool and make sure you tick on the parameter *Find only closest feature*.

Comment: It worked! It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @David if this answered your question, you should accept it.

Comment: I've just done it. Thanks!